# Iterating over a list of integers using map and using a list of functions

Tags: python, lambda, filter

Hi guys Im trying to write a code that uses a list of functions and a list of integers and only returns the ones that have at least 1 true in the list of functions like so:

```
tuple(lambda func,data:filter(lambda x:map(lambda y:y(x)==true,func),data))

func=(lambda x: x>3,lambda x: x%2==0)
data=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

so the list should return 
4,6,8,10
but instead it returns the entire list,does anybody knows why?

P.S I know it can be done very easily in a different way, but Its a lambda exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression like the following:

```
tuple(filter(lambda x: any(filter(lambda f: f(x), func)), data))
```

So,

```
In [17]: func=(lambda x: x>3,lambda x: x%2==0)
    ...: data=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
    ...:
    ...:

In [18]: tuple(filter(lambda x: any(filter(lambda f: f(x), func)), data))
Out[18]: (2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Also note, your expression raises a `TypeError`, so I don't know what you mean about it returning the whole list.

It would probably be more readable to use something like:

```
In [23]: tuple(
    ...:     x for x in data
    ...:     if any(f(x) for f in func)
    ...: )
Out[23]: (2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Or without `any` (a ridiculous constraint)

```
In [29]: tuple(filter(lambda x: tuple(filter(None, map(lambda f: f(x), func))), data))
Out[29]: (2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but in order to solve this riddle I must only use map,filter and lambda. any is not allowed.

Comment: @AlexK OK, then *implement `any`*. That is very straight-forward

Answer (score 0):

It's more Pythonic to map these functions using list comprehensions:

```
data = range(1, 11)
funcs = (lambda x: x > 3, lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
new_data = [x for x in l if all(f(x) for f in funcs)]
# new_data == [4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm trying to understand this lambda exercise, I need to stick to this pattern.